# Send multiple values to Arduino with C#

Tags: c#, arduino, arduino-ide

I'm very new to Arduino and C#.
I want to create a GUI that allows for turning LEDs on/off with the digitalWrite method as well as individual analog modulation using the analogWrite method.
I have successfully managed to create a form that can turn the LEDs on/off, however I'm not sure how to go about sending the analogWrite value for modulating the intensity of the LED?

My Arduino code so far is:

```
#define BaudRate 9600
#define greenLaser    10
#define redLaser    11
char incomingOption;
int power;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(greenLaser, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redLaser, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(BaudRate);
}
void loop()
{
     incomingOption = Serial.read();
     switch(incomingOption){
        case '1':
          // Turn ON LED
          digitalWrite(redLaser, HIGH);
          break;
        case '0':
          // Turn OFF LED
          digitalWrite(redLaser, LOW);
          break;
        case '3':
          // Turn ON LED
          digitalWrite(greenLaser, HIGH);
          break;
        case '4':
          // Turn ON LED
          digitalWrite(greenLaser, LOW);
          break;
        case '5':
          // Turn OFF all Lasers
          digitalWrite(greenLaser, LOW);
          digitalWrite(redLaser, LOW);
     }
}
```

My C# code is:

```
try
            {
                serialPort1.Write("0"); //send on signal to Arduino
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

I'm stuck on how I could send a pin-specific value for the analogWrite method if I can only send individual bytes.

Comment: Have you already tried to do the analogWrite part? Include it in your above code.

Comment: You don't have to only send one byte to issue a command. Multiple bytes combined into a single command or even multiple commands are possible just be formating those bytes in a certain way that both sides understand by also using a command terminating byte.

Comment: First of all, this is working fine? Why you don't follow the traditional method ´if(serial.available())´?